# want to annotate in pages, but it keeps inserting drawing (iPad - iOS)

Tags: ios, ipad, pages

I want to use my ipencil to annotate a docx in pages like I do PDFs in PDFExpert. There are youtube videos showing you can decide whether you are drawing or annotating with a tab on top of the palette, but I don't get the tabs. I can select smart annotate from the ... menu at the top, but as soon as I select a pen from the palette it inserts a drawing again! What is wrong? I'm fully updated.

I figured out annotation is only the circles on the far right https://appleinsider.com/inside/ipad/tips/how-to-use-smart-annotations-on-ipad not the rest of the tools, but now I can't scroll up or down with my finger. PDFExpert, if you edit with your pen, you can navigate with your finger. Is that unique to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable **Only Draw with Apple Pencil** in *Settings → Apple Pencil*.

[image]

You can only draw with the Apple Pencil and scroll with your fingers when this option is enabled.

Comment: It's still better to be able to draw with your finger if you don't have your ipencil handy, but only with the ipencil when the ipencil is around, which is how pdfexpert works, but today pages is working right too. Anyway, I gave you the points :-)